# get a set of unique values from nested list

Tags: python, set

I have this nested list `X_train`

```
X_train = [['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
 ['sunny', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['sunny', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'mild', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['sunny', 'mild', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'hot', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE']]
```

I want to generate a list where the nth row of `X_train` contains the set of unique values in the   th column of `X_train`. So the expected output should be:

```
[{'overcast', 'rainy', 'sunny'},
 {'cool', 'hot', 'mild'},
 {'high', 'normal'},
 {'FALSE', 'TRUE'}]
```

My code is as follows:

```
questions=[]
f=set({w for row in X_train for w in row})
questions+=[f]
```

The output for that is like the gatherings of all unique values, which is not my expected output. How should I correct to fix my output as expected (I am advised to use set but I am not sure how to fix it in a right way)

```
[{'FALSE',
  'TRUE',
  'cool',
  'high',
  'hot',
  'mild',
  'normal',
  'overcast',
  'rainy',
  'sunny'}]
```

Any ideas to help me out please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `zip()` the list to get the columns. Unpacking the columns with `*` is the trick here. Then just take sets of the columns:

```
X_train = [['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
 ['sunny', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
 ['sunny', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'mild', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['sunny', 'mild', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE'],
 ['overcast', 'hot', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
 ['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE']]

values = [set(col) for col in zip(*X_train)]
```

Gives you values:

```
[{'overcast', 'rainy', 'sunny'},
 {'cool', 'hot', 'mild'},
 {'high', 'normal'},
 {'FALSE', 'TRUE'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A concise way of getting your expected output is with: `list(map(set, zip(*X_train)))`.

`zip(*X_train)` switches rows and columns, giving something roughly equivalent to:

```
[['sunny',
  'sunny',
  'overcast',
  'rainy',
  'rainy',
  'rainy',
  'overcast',
  'sunny',
  'sunny',
  'rainy',
  'sunny',
  'overcast',
  'overcast',
  'rainy'],
 ['hot',
  'hot',
  'hot',
  'mild',
  'cool',
  'cool',
  'cool',
  'mild',
  'cool',
  'mild',
  'mild',
  'mild',
  'hot',
  'mild'],
 ['high',
  'high',
  'high',
  'high',
  'normal',
  'normal',
  'normal',
  'high',
  'normal',
  'normal',
  'normal',
  'high',
  'normal',
  'high'],
 ['FALSE',
  'TRUE',
  'FALSE',
  'FALSE',
  'FALSE',
  'TRUE',
  'TRUE',
  'FALSE',
  'FALSE',
  'FALSE',
  'TRUE',
  'TRUE',
  'FALSE',
  'TRUE']]
```

Then each list in the list is mapped to a `set`, and the `map` object is converted to a `list`.

Comment: In 3.x, `map` returns a generator, and you will need to create a `list` from the results explicitly.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks, I've edited to include this.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use zip then you can use this method but it is very long but simple and very basic

```
X_train = [['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'TRUE'],
['overcast', 'hot', 'high', 'FALSE'],
['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
['rainy', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
['overcast', 'cool', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
['sunny', 'mild', 'high', 'FALSE'],
['sunny', 'cool', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
['rainy', 'mild', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
['sunny', 'mild', 'normal', 'TRUE'],
['overcast', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE'],
['overcast', 'hot', 'normal', 'FALSE'],
['rainy', 'mild', 'high', 'TRUE']]
f=[]
temp1=set()
temp2=set()
temp3=set()
temp4=set()
for i in X_train:
    temp1.add(i[0])
    temp2.add(i[1])
    temp3.add(i[2])
    temp4.add(i[3])
f.append(temp1)
f.append(temp2)
f.append(temp3)
f.append(temp4)
del(temp1)
del(temp2)
del(temp3)
del(temp4)
print(f)
```